# Changed BE API url to hostname. <not working>

Tags: java, reactjs, jenkins, frontend, devops

In my project, FE was using BE API Url like - http://171.28.106.18:32514/.
Now this has been changed to hostname from devops team which is - http://project-backend-qa:8080

Now I am not able to hit any API's from my application.
Screenshot below -

[image]

On BE side(JAVA), this has been written -

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","PATCH")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
```

BE is allowing all origins, still not able to access the hostname. Any idea what I am missing -

Answer (score 0):

Handling the CORS issue in the backend is better. The changes below work for me.

As a temporary solution, you can use a Chrome plugin (eg: [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)) to disable the security checks.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```